# "Get a place's open and close hours and if DateTime.Now is between mark as open " works locally but not on the server after published

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem with times when debugging locally versus when published on a server.

My need is to know if a store is open between 2 times such as:

```
if ((timeNow >= openHour) && (timeNow <= closeHour))
```

And if it is, tell the user if the store is closed or open.

**Edit**

**My question basically:**
The Cron Job that updates the stores' state every minute queries the stores' timezones and for each store adapt its DateTime.UtcNow to that timezone, and it works when debugging locally but not when I've published the code and query the stores' state.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

**StoreHours.cs**

```
public class StoreHour : AuditableEntities
{
    public StoreHour()
    {

    }

    public Guid StoreHourId { get; set; }
    public Guid DayOfTheWeekId { get; set; }
    public virtual DayOfTheWeek DayOfTheWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenHour { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseHour { get; set; }
    public Guid PlaceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Place Place { get; set; }
}
```

**AppDbContext.cs ( seed data )**

```
// Hours for the first store
var cscOpeningHour = DateTime.ParseExact("11:30:00 AM", "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
cscOpeningHour = DateTime.SpecifyKind(cscOpeningHour, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var cscClosingHour = DateTime.ParseExact("10:00:00 PM", "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
cscClosingHour = DateTime.SpecifyKind(cscClosingHour, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// Hours for the second store ( have multiple because closing time is the next day ( 02:00:00 AM )
var jOpeningHour1 = DateTime.ParseExact("12:00:00 AM", "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
jOpeningHour1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(jOpeningHour1, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var jClosingHour1 = DateTime.ParseExact("02:00:00 AM", "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
jClosingHour1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(jClosingHour1, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var jOpeningHour2 = DateTime.ParseExact("05:00:00 PM", "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
jOpeningHour2 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(jOpeningHour2, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var jClosingHour2 = DateTime.ParseExact("11:59:59 PM", "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
jClosingHour2 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(jClosingHour2, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// Seed data
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreHour>().HasData(new StoreHour
        {
            StoreHourId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            DayOfTheWeekId = mondayDayOfTheWeekId,
            OpenHour = cscOpeningHour,
            CloseHour = cscClosingHour,
            PlaceId = cscPlaceId
        });
```

**UpdateDeviceCommandHandler.cs**

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(UpdateDeviceCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var devices = await repository.GetAllDevicesWithRelatedData();
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            var count = await repository.GetNumber(device.DeviceId);

            var thePlace = await placeRepository.GetPlaceByIdWithRelatedData(device.Place.PlaceId);

            var timeNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                              DateTime.Now,
                              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(thePlace.Timezone.Name));

            var day = DateTime.UtcNow.DayOfWeek.ToString();

            if (thePlace.StoreHours.Count() > 7)
            {
                // OpenHour and CloseHour are DateTime properties
                // returns "12:00:00 AM"
                var openHour1 = thePlace.StoreHours.OrderBy(d => d.OpenHour).Select(d => d.OpenHour).First().ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
                // returns "2:00:00 AM"
                var closeHour1 = thePlace.StoreHours.OrderBy(d => d.CloseHour).Select(d => d.CloseHour).First().ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
                // returns "05:00:00 PM"
                var openHour2 = thePlace.StoreHours.OrderByDescending(d => d.OpenHour).Select(d => d.OpenHour).First().ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
                // returns "11:59:59 PM"
                var closeHour2 = thePlace.StoreHours.OrderByDescending(d => d.CloseHour).Select(d => d.CloseHour).First().ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

                // returns today's date and time: mm/dd/yyyy - 12:00:00 AM
                // Which is the right time converted to the place's timezone
                var theOpenHour1 = DateTime.Parse(openHour1);
                theOpenHour1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                              theOpenHour1,
                              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(thePlace.Timezone.Name));
                var theCloseHour1 = DateTime.Parse(closeHour1);
                theCloseHour1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                              theCloseHour1,
                              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(thePlace.Timezone.Name));
                var theOpenHour2 = DateTime.Parse(openHour2);
                theOpenHour2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                              theOpenHour2,
                              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(thePlace.Timezone.Name));
                var theCloseHour2 = DateTime.Parse(closeHour2);
                theCloseHour2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                              theCloseHour2,
                              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(thePlace.Timezone.Name));

                if ((timeNow >= theOpenHour1) && (timeNow <= theCloseHour1)
                     || (timeNow >= theOpenHour2) && (timeNow <= theCloseHour2))
                {
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        device.Ratio = (double)device.Count / (double)count;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count += 1;
                        device.Ratio = (double)device.Count / (double)count;
                    }

                    if (device.Ratio == 2)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                    if (...)
                    {
                        //
                    }

                    repository.Update(device);
                }
                else
                {
                    //

                    repository.Update(device);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                var openHour = thePlace.StoreHours.Select(d => d.OpenHour).First().ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
                var closeHour = thePlace.StoreHours.Select(d => d.CloseHour).First().ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

                DateTime dtOpen = DateTime.Parse(openHour);
                dtOpen = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                              dtOpen,
                              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(thePlace.Timezone.Name));
                DateTime dtClose = DateTime.Parse(closeHour);
                dtClose = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                              dtClose,
                              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(thePlace.Timezone.Name));

                if ((timeNow >= dtOpen) && (timeNow <= dtClose))
                {
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        device.Ratio = (double)device.Count/ (double)count;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count += 1;
                        device.Ratio = (double)device.Count/ (double)count;
                    }

                    if (device.Ratio == 2)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                    if (...)
                    {
                        //
                    }

                    repository.Update(device);
                }
                else
                {
                    //

                    repository.Update(device);
                }
            }

        await repository.SaveChanges();

        return Unit.Value;

        }
```

As @JonasH said I should use TimeSpan but before I do I really want to understand why it's working locally and not remotely. I'm converting the invalid date's time "12:00:00 AM" into a valid DateTime converted to the place's TimeZone ( right before the if statement ). When I debug it it works because the times compared are the same day and the right times, what confuses me is why not on the server, what is it that I'm not converting or not doing that makes the server not do it.

I'm sure it has to do with time conversion as my computer gets the local time but I don't know how the server gets it wrong after having converted the time values in the code.

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Send it from the client.

Comment: That's a very interesting way which I think is the way to do it, however I have a question on that, the if statement is in a Cron Job that updates the stores state every minute and so it doesn't wait for the user to query it, basically the Cron Job needs to know itself the current time of the place and compare it to its hours and I think that's where I'm confused on how to get the time for the Cron Job to do its updates

Comment: It will be helpful to know what business usecase you are trying to solve...

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking how to determine if a store is open based on a time specified by a user in an unknown timezone, or are you asking how to update a store's open state from a cron job? In the case of the former, you need to determine the user's offset from UTC. In the case of the latter, you clearly know the timezone the store is in if you're updating it from a cronjob. Perhaps [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones) can help there.

Comment: I think I understand my problem from both your questions, basically I'm trying to get the store's timezone without having it saved anywhere. The Cron Job needs to query the stores' timezones and for each store adapt its DateTime.Now to that timezone, that's how it can update the fact that it is open or not right ?

Comment: The open/closeness of a store should be invariant on the position of the observer.

Comment: I see, I've updated my code to explain the problem better

Answer (score 3):

> My need is to know if a store is open between 2 times.

I would suggest storing the opening/closing times as TimeSpans representing the time of day (i.e. the time from the start of the day), and the timezone for the store.

.Net 6 are introducing a [TimeOnly](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#introducing-the-dateonly-and-timeonly-types) type that provides a better representation of a "time of day" than a timespan. And there is also [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) for a more complete set of date/time related types.

You can then use TimeZoneInfo to get the current time of day for a specific time-zone:

```
var timeOfDayForStore = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                                  DateTime.Now,
                                  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(myStoreTimeZone))
                                 .TimeOfDay;
if(myStoreOpenTime < timeOfDayForStore && myStoreCloseTime > timeOfDayForStore){
    ...
}
```

Note that this assumes the store is not open over midnight.

Comment: So should I have a property on the store entity called TimezoneId and save an id of it to use it to convert the time to the store timezone ?

Comment: @Sacha Person, yes, that is at least how I would approach the problem. There are other ways to do it, and I do not claim to be an authority on the subject. but it is a complicated subject, and fairly easy to get wrong, so careful consideration is probably a good idea.

Comment: I see, I think this is the answer, also I have another question, if a store's open hour is 11:30 AM, should it be saved as var openHour = DateTime.Parse("11:30:00 AM", "hh:mm:ss tt", ...) and then openHour = DateTime.SpecifyKind(openHour, Kind.Utc) or is there another way to make sure it is a time related to its timezone ?

Comment: I would use [TimeSpan.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparse?view=net-5.0) rather than the DateTime methods. Since you want the time from midnight that the store opens, not a specific moment in time.

Comment: To make sure I understand, isn't the hours of a store set at a specific moment in time set in a timezone ?

Comment: @Sacha Person, If a store opens at 8AM, I would assume it does not only open today at 8AM, but also tomorrow, and probably 8AM every workday as long as the store is open, or the opening times changes. You could then, if you wish, convert these rules to a list DateTimes representing the specific moment in time for each day the store is opening.

Comment: So as expected it worked locally, but it doesn't on the server. I have tried to do the timespan but it's a little harder to get the times and create new times ( at least at my level ), I've added the code I'm trying to make work to the post can you take a look and see if I'm doing something wrong and if it can work with DateTime instead of TimeSpan ? Thank you so much !

Comment: @JonasH It seems you misspelt dotnet 6's `TimeOnly` struct, or possibly JonSkeet's NodaTime's `LocalTime` struct.

Comment: @Aron added to the answer.

Comment: @Sacha Person In the example above you are comparing dateTimes that have a valid date (i.e. 'Now') with dateTimes without a valid date (i.e. DateTime.Parse("12:00:00"))). This is clearly incorrect, and is the reason I recommend using a time-specific datatype to represent "time of day", it lets the type system help you avoid errors.

Comment: @JonasH I totally understand your point and I really want to try your idea and use TimeSpan but before I do I really want to understand why it's working locally and not remotely. When you say it's invalid you're right, however I'm converting the invalid date's time "12:00:00 AM" into a valid DateTime converted to the place's TimeZone ( right before the if statement ). When I debug it it works because the times compared are the same day and the right times, what confuses me is why not on the server, what is it that I'm not converting or not doing that makes the server not do it.

Comment: I've updated my post as well to make sure I'm not doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you get a `DateTime` from a javascript / typescript client it should contain information about the timezone and the comparison should work. One common pitfall is if you store this value in a database using DateTime (and not DateTimeOffset) you will lose this information and the comparison (after round trip to DB) will be wrong.

It is a bit unclear what you're asking for but it might be that you should just store the `openHour` and 'closeHour' as UTC (or with offset information). It looks like you're always getting `timeNow` on the server so maybe it's just that?

Comment: I know it was a little unclear I was still figuring out my problem, I apologize for that, my problem I think is I'm trying to get the store's timezone without having it saved anywhere. The Cron Job that updates the stores state every minute and so doesn't wait on the user to query it needs to query the stores' timezones and for each store adapt its DateTime.Now to that timezone, that's how it can update the fact that it is open or not with the right time right ? And openHour should be saved as UTC ( that's done ) but how to add offset information ?